# How to determine arg type in c++

Tags: c++, c, googletest

in gcc, I can use following code:

```
#define is_t(smth, type) ({int is_t_result; if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(smth), type)) {is_t_result = 1;}; is_t_result;})
```

but when I run it in googletest(c++), it raise

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘__typeof__’
```

is there alternative to implement `is_t` in cpp?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complicated question, because there are many different ways to "detect types", depending on what it is you are trying to accomplish. There are basically two different categories of "type checking": compile-time and run-time. In terms of compile-time checking, it is very common to use "[duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)" with C++ templates (it works if it satisfies the implicit requirements); however, there are some cases where this is not sufficient, and [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) and [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) provide ways to enforce requirements more explicitly, while [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) allows one to refer to the type that would be returned by an expression. Type conversion at runtime is less common in C++ (usually it is done implicitly through "dynamic dispatch", a.k.a. virtual functions); however, in terms of explicitly checking the runtime type of an object, there is the [`dynamic_cast<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) mechanism.

Long-story short, though, your `is_t()` macro is probably best replaced by the builtin mechanisms for type-detection in C++. If you are using older versions of C++, [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) provides widely compatible equivalents that work across many C++ compilers and both C++98 and C++11. Doing so will make it much clearer what you mean by the variable being of that type. (E.g. is it declared to be exactly of that type, does it have that runtime type, is it declared to be of a type that is assignable to the other type).

Comment: I just wanna determine c type(int, float double, char*) and make googletest pass, is there simple way? I don't write c++, just use googletest

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that you "don't write C++, just use Google Test"... Google Test is a unit testing framework for C++... I don't understand how one can write tests without also understanding the code being tested. Your best best is to define "is_t(Type, x)" as "typeid(T) ==  typeid(x)", but this does an exact comparison on the type... it doesn't consider polymorphic relations. This is why a macro like that is confusing.